# Understanding 落实政策

Tags: translation, word, idioms

I've often read about 给 XXX 落实政策。This thing seems to be *very* flexible.

For example, 落实疫情防控政策 and 给烈士子女落实政策。

How to contextually translate this phrase into English?

Answer (score 1):

落实 - to implement/carried out; workable/practical

**落实**疫情防控**政策** - **to implement/carried out .... policy**.

给烈士子女**落实政策** - provide .... **workable/practical policy**.

Comment: Yes, this is a fair translation. However, **implement** merely means that the policy was put out, it does not stress that doing it correctly and thoroughly was important, as in 落实。It is, I believe, more similar to a plain old 执行。

Answer (score 1):

落：落下：set down, set out, set in motion
实：实现：bring about

落实疫情防控政策
set in motion real, effective epidemic prevention policy

给烈士子女落实政策
set out real, effective policies for the children of our martyrs

Comment: I feel like 'set in motion' or 'bring about' could work, but 'set out' has a different connotation. If you're 'setting out' a policy then what you're doing is determining and finalising its formulation, not its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic way to render the notion of 'implement correctly/thoroughly', as you suggest in one of your comments here, would be to translate the phrase as

"**put into place/effect ... measures**"